# What is the maximum covalency of oxygen?

Tags: bond, valence-bond-theory

My text says it to be 4. I believe it's 2. Is there any compound where covalency of 4 is observed?

Comment: Guess they mean coordination compounds.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: [Basic beryllium acetate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_beryllium_acetate) will do.

Comment: Yeah basic beryllium acetate has four coordinate O and can be thought of as significantly covalent due do the polarisability of Be. There are also numerous three coordinate species containing oxonium ions eg Me3O+

Comment: $\ce{H4O^{2+}}$ is also an option.

Answer (score 5):

We know the maximum covalent is at least 3 with such species as  $\ce{H3O+}$.  Also the pyrylium ion (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrylium_salt) has an oxygen covalency of 3 by forming a pi bond for the third bond.

Can we get 4-coordination?  As mentioned by @Rob, yes.   @Rob's comment states that basic beryllium acetate appears to have 4-coordinate, covalently bound oxygen.

And it check out.  Basic beryllium acetate, $\ce {Be4O(C2H3O2)6}$, has the four-coordinate oxygen in the center, then four beryllium atoms coordinated to this oxygen at the vertices of a tetrahedron, then an acetate group bridging each edge of the tetrahedron.  In addition to beryllium, zinc forms a similarly structured basic acetate, which can be obtained by heating normal zinc acetate (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc_acetate).

Might the central oxygen be mostly ionically bonded?  Magnesium and heavier alkaline earth metals, which form more strongly ionic bonds with oxygen, are not known to form such a basic acetate structure.  This corroborates the hypothesis that *covalent* bonding of the central, four-coordinate oxygen is involved.